# Delete zeros immediately after a delimiter

Tags: r

I have a vector like this `vec <- c("ADNI_0002", "ADNI_0008", "ADNI_0112", "B0012")`. I am trying to remove `0` immediately after `_` to get `ADNI_2, ADNI_8, ADNI_112, B0012`.

I tried gsub `gsub("_[0]","", vec)`, but this won't give me the desired result. What would be the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
vec <- c("ADNI_0002", "ADNI_0008", "ADNI_0112", "B0012")
gsub("_0+", "_", vec)
#[1] "ADNI_2"   "ADNI_8"   "ADNI_112" "B0012"
```

Your original solution doesn't work for a few reasons.  The first being that you don't tell it in any way to account for multiple 0s.  Using 0+ in the gsub will tell it "match 1 or more 0s".  The other issue is that yours matches _0 and then replaces it with nothing but you want to retain the underscore so that should be in the replacement portion.

As a sidenote you don't need to use the brackets here around 0 since you are just specifying a single character.  The square brackets are nice when specifying ranges or multiple possible characters.  The brackets wouldn't mess anything up - they're just not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sub:

```
sub("_0+", '_', vec)
[1] "ADNI_2"   "ADNI_8"   "ADNI_112" "B0012"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach by converting to `numeric`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(vec, "(?<=_)\\d+",  function(x) as.numeric(x))
[1] "ADNI_2"   "ADNI_8"   "ADNI_112" "B0012"
```

Comment: Ingenious! The idea behind this deserve a triple upvote by every user!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gsub` like below

```
> gsub("(?<=_)0+", "", vec, perl = TRUE)
[1] "ADNI_2"   "ADNI_8"   "ADNI_112" "B0012"
```